# На практике делают кнопки через css или фотошоп?

Tags: css, photoshop

Вот, например есть кнопка. Если заниматься фронтендом сайта, то её как лучше делать через CSS или рисовать в фотошопе ?

```css
a.knopka {
  color: #fff; 
  text-decoration: none; 
  user-select: none;
  background: rgb(212,75,56);
  padding: .7em 1.5em; /
  outline: none; 
} 
a.knopka:hover { background: rgb(232,95,76); } 
a.knopka:active { background: rgb(152,15,0); }
```

```html
<a href="#" class="knopka">кнопка</a>
```

Comment: какой-то странный вопрос

Comment: Я полагаю раньше делали кнопки изображениями, но сейчас другие времена. Даже Edge теперь поддерживает все новшества html и css так что потребности делать негибкие к изменению кнопки картинками более нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Бесспорно, раньше создание всех кнопок в *Photoshop* было очень широкой практикой. Это позволяло без проблем отображать их в разных браузерах, ведь ранее не все браузера поддерживали те же градиенты и прочее. К тому же, ранее было в моде всякие градиенты, мигающие кнопки. Но недостаток у этого тоже был. Он заключался в том, что очень было сложно создать объект, который при изменении размеров сохранял нормальную текстуру, по этому большинство сайтов были с фиксированной шириной и высотой объектов.

В наше время почти все браузеры стали поддерживать градиенты, анимации с помощью CSS и прочее. Много багов исправили и даже новый браузер от *Microsoft - Edge* стал нормально поддерживать все стили. По этому, если вы знаете, как правильно сверстать нормальную кнопку с помощью *CSS*, то лучше это сделать только с помощью него, что бы объект был гибким и ваш сайт не прогружался 2 часа из за огромного количества картинок.